# devcon disable fails on win7 for usb camera. why?

Tags: windows, drivers

I'm trying to disable/enable USB camera using devcon. It fails with the following output:
c:\temp\devcon>devcon   disable "USB\VID_199E*"

```
USB\VID_199E&PID_8207&MI_00\8&11CAF5B4&0&0000               : Disable failed
USB\VID_199E&PID_8207\16210163                              : Disable failed
```

I execute devcon in a console run with admin privilegs

What could be the reason?

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for downvoting! An explanation would be nice. Anyway, if you could find a similar question on SO with a _working_ answer, please tell me - i couldn't find it. I've tried to follow instructions from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rtaDu8QStQM - no success.

Comment: "DISABLE FAILED NO DEVICES DISABLED" DEVCON.EXE | HOW TO DISABLE DEVICES FROM COMMAND PROMPT" Try this link:
http://delphintipz.blogspot.com.es/2012/07/disable-failed-no-devices-disabled.html

Answer (score 1):

I have such issue when tried 32-bit devcon.exe (located in Program Files(x86)) on 64bit Windows 7.
Solution is to use 64-bit version of devcon.exe

Also, you need to run devcon with admin privileges (ie, start cmd as Administrator, then run devcon).